# WKWebView shows a blank screen on OSX with no output

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, webview, wkwebview

For some reason, the WKWebView just shows a blank screen with **no errors**

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView?



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView?.navigationDelegate = self
    let url=URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    webView?.load(URLRequest(url: url!))

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
}
```

Like I said, no errors, and it just shows a blank screen.
The storyboard looks like this:

[Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhWCw.png)

Comment: Did you connect the `webView` outlet to the webview?

Comment: How to do that @Willeke?

Comment: Google "xcode connect outlet"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow your application to have outgoing connections.

In your `Target` go to `Capabilities`, enable the `App SandBox` and check the `Outgoing Connections`.

[image: Outgoing Connections]

Comment: I almost Googled the whole universe before I got this, I don't know it is never stated in any WebView tutorial ever!